# Let as syntactic sugar for lambda

Tags: scheme, lisp, sicp

Is the following how a `let` statement resolves in terms of `lambda`?

```
(let((a 4)(b 5)) (+ a b))
-->
((lambda (a b) (+ a b)) 4 5)
```

Is the general form something along the lines of:

```
(lambda (key1 key2 ...) <body> (val1 val2 ...))
-->
(let ((key1 val1) (key2 val2) ...) <body>)
```

What's the advantage of using the `let` syntax? Is it just the easier readability placing the key/value pair next to each other?

Comment: Yes, this is explained in the book in [here](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-12.html#%_sec_1.3.2) and [here](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-21.html#%_idx_3110). Also in this blog [post](http://qr.ae/RUymgf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only easier readability; it is easier to write code using `let` than it is to write code that uses `lambda` to express `let`. Consider:

```
(let ((x 2)
      (y 3))
  (let ((u (+ x y))
        (v (* x y)))
    (display "let version:\n")
    (for-each display (list x ", " y "\n" u ", " v "\n"))))
```

```
let version:
2, 3
5, 6
```

And a `lambda` version of the same construct:

```
((lambda (x y)
   ((lambda (u v)
       (display "lambda version:\n")
       (for-each display (list x ", " y "\n" u ", " v "\n")))
    (+ x y) (* x y))) 2 3)
```

```
lambda version:
2, 3
5, 6
```

Both versions work, but the `let` version expresses *intent* through use of an appropriate syntax. The `lambda` version expresses intent only through the semantics of its construction. If you are unaware if the idiom that allows the expression of the idea of `let` binding, or if you can't piece together what is happening by analyzing the code, the meaning of the `lambda` version is opaque. But the `let` version clearly states its intent by using syntax dedicated to `let` binding.

Further, as `let` binding scenarios get more complex, using `let` offloads a substantial portion of that complexity to the syntax. The above example is a simple nested `let`, and it is already easy to make mistakes in the `lambda` version. You have to be sure that the parentheses are placed correctly (I actually managed to get one out of place when writing the example code), and the final version places all of the variable identifiers at the beginning of the construction, with all of the bound values at the end. This means that to understand the `lambda` version you must keep referencing the beginning and the end to understand what is happening in the body.

Generally speaking, `lambda` expresses a very general idea, but `let` expresses a more specific idea that is often needed. The advantage of `let` syntax is that it allows you to express the more specific idea easily, concisely, and readably in a way that is less error-prone than always expressing the specific idea by implementing it in terms of the  more general idea.

Answer (score 2):

```
(lambda (key1 key2 ...) <body> (val1 val2 ...))
-->
(let ((key1 val1) (key2 val2) ...) <body>)
```

The first pattern is actually like this:

```
((lambda (par1 par2 ...) <body>) arg1 arg2 ...)
-->
(let ((par1 arg1) (par2 arg2) ...) <body>)
```

The function has parameters. Common Lisp has positional, optional, rest and keyword parameters.

The function form has argument forms. Each argument form gets evaluated and the function then gets called with the arguments values. The parameters (local variables) get bound to the arguments values and the body gets executed.

The main benefit of a let is a question of easier seeing which parameter has which argument form and how many arguments (and possibly which) one has to provide.

Imagine:

```
((lambda (a b c d e f)
 
 <long body>           ; and yes the body can get long

 )

 1 2 3 4 5 5)
```

Be warned, there is a lot of code where the body is longer than five lines.

The `let` moves the argument forms to the top and it is easier to see what the environment is in which the body gets evaluated:

```
(let ((a 1)
      (b 2)
      (c 3)
      (d 4)
      (e 5)
      (d 6))

   <long body>

   )
```

or even

```
(let ((a 1) (b 2) (c 3) (d 4) (e 5) (d 6))

   <long body>

   )
```